# Border colour isn't changing if input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, border

I have a simple script written in PHP and Javascript which changes the border colour of an `input` field if it is empty.

When using the code below, the border colour doesn't change and the following error displays:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
echo'
<script>
document.getElementById("username").style.border = "1px solid red";
</script>
';
}
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your script is running before the html is loaded. Read up on how JavaScript and HTML are loaded

Comment: @SterlingArcher Ah, that may be the cause. I need the php to run before the html though... is there a work-around for this?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Actually, the code runs after the form has been submitted.. wouldn't that mean the html has already been loaded?

Comment: No, because the page is reloaded, so the DOM has to render again.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Could I call in the function when I check if the input field is empty and have the function at the bottom of the page _(if you get what I mean)_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `window.onload = function () {...}` to the top of your script.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {

        echo "
            <script>
                window.onload = function () {

                    document.getElementById('username').style.border = '1px solid red';
                };
            </script>";
    }
}
```

---

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that it was as simple as adding `window.onload = function () {` to the code... this is my first time using Javascript _(I'm a php guy!)_